# Box plot for continuous data in Python

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, continuous

I have a csv file with 2 columns:

- col1- `Timestamp` data(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms (8 months data))
- col2 : Heat data (continuous variable) .

Since there are almost 50k record, I would like to partition the col1(timestamp col) into months or weeks and then apply box plot on the heat data w.r.t timestamp.
I tried in R,it takes a long time. Need help to do in Python.  I think I need to use `seaborn.boxplot`.

Please guide.

Comment: You want to make 8 plots of monthly data?

Comment: @wwii: Yes. And also partition heat data into 5- gps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Group by Frequency then plot groups**

First [Read your csv data into a Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

```
import numpy as np
import Pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# assumes NO header line in csv
df = pd.read_csv('\file\path', names=['time','temp'], parse_dates=[0])
```

I will use some fake data, 30 days of hourly samples.

```
heat = np.random.random(24*30) * 100
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=24*30, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':dates,'temp':heat})
```

Set the timestamps as the DataFrame's index

```
df = df.set_index('time')
```

Now group by by the period you want, seven days for this example

```
gb = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='7D'))
```

Now you can plot each group separately

```
for g, week in gb2:
    #week.plot()
    week.boxplot()
    plt.title(f'Week Of {g.date()}')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

And... I didn't realize you could do this but it is pretty cool

```
ax = gb.boxplot(subplots=False)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(),rotation=30)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: Weekly Temps]

---

```
heat = np.random.random(24*300) * 100
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=24*300, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':dates,'temp':heat})
df = df.set_index('time')
```

To partition the data in five time periods then get weekly boxplots of each:

Determine the total timespan; divide by five; create a frequency alias; then groupby

```
dt = df.index[-1] - df.index[0]
dt = dt/5
alias = f'{dt.total_seconds()}S'
gb = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=alias))
```

Each group is a DataFrame so iterate over the groups; create *weekly* groups from each and boxplot them.

```
for g,d_frame in gb:
    gb_tmp = d_frame.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='7D'))
    ax = gb_tmp.boxplot(subplots=False)
    plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(),rotation=90)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

There might be a better way to do this, if so I'll post it or maybe someone will fill free to edit this.  Looks like this could lead to the last group not having a full set of data. ...

If you know that your data is periodic you can just use slices to split it up.

```
n = len(df) // 5
for tmp_df in (df[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(df), n)):
    gb_tmp = tmp_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='7D'))
    ax = gb_tmp.boxplot(subplots=False)
    plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(),rotation=90)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

---

[Frequency aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)
[pandas.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)
[pandas.Grouper()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Grouper.html?highlight=pandas.grouper#pandas.Grouper)

Comment: Thanks! But if I have to cut the intervals of the heat data(as it is huge),how do i do it?

Comment: @Unknown - `cut the intervals` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I have 50k heat data,And would want to partition into some 5-6 groups and plot for each month/week

Comment: How do i replicate it to histogram? I mean, Month wise normalised histogram for heat data

Comment: @Unknown you plot a histogram instead of a boxplot.?

Comment: Yes.Please let me know if you could help me with this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434784/python-plot-month-wise-histogramnormalised